# java thread synchronized & lock no effect?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, synchronized

so much confused why I get a random result while doing 'i++' in a synchronized or a locked method?

```
public class aaa implements Runnable {
    static int count = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        aaa aaa = new aaa();
        aaa.create();
    }
    public void create() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            aaa thread = new aaa();
            executor.execute(thread);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (true){
            if(executor.isTerminated()){
                System.out.println("a " + count);
           break;
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.test();
    }
    public void test() {
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        try {
            lock.lock();
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

OR:

```
    public  synchronized void test() {
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
        }
```

the result is a random number sometimes 1000 sometimes 998, 999 ...etc and the print from inside the 'test' method is not in a sequence, it is like :

```
867
836
825
824
821
820
819
817
816
a 999
```

However, if it is in a synchronized block, everything looks good:

```
    public void test() {
        synchronized (aaa.class) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
```

the result:

```
993
994
995
996
997
998
999
1000
a 1000
```

I think all of the methods above should give me the same result 1000, and the self increment should be in a sequence, but only the last method works.What is wrong with the code? Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating multiple instances of aaa, each instance creates its own ReentrantLock, and every thread in execution smoothly acquires a lock from its own instance.

```
public void test() {
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        try {
            lock.lock();
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

Since there are multiple instances of aaa, each thread is running on its own instance and the synchronized method uses current object of aaa.class

```
public  synchronized void test() {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
```

The reason for getting a proper result in this approach is, you are using the aaa.class as an object to the synchronization

```
public void test() {
    synchronized (aaa.class) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

The solution is, reuse the same lock(ReentrantLock) across all the threads. Defining the lock in the same level as the variable count would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a single mutex, i.e.

```
static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

Your synchronized method does not work since you are creating **N** `aaa` instances then, every (non static) method is different (with their own mutex).

Your `synchronized (aaa.class)` works since `aaa.class` is the same `Object` for all `aaa` instances and methods.

Then, if you need synchronize the method be sure it is the same for all threads, e.g. if `test` is `static` will be the same for all

```
@Override
public void run() {
    test();
}

public static synchronized void test() {
        count++;
}
```

but you can inject a *"counter class"*, e.g.

```
class Counter {
    int count = 0;
    // non static but synchronized for all (since they use the same `counter` object)
    synchronized void inc() {
        count++;
    }
}
```

to be used for all threads

```
...
SyncTest thread = new SyncTest(counter); // <== the same
...
```

(full code)

```
public class SyncTest implements Runnable {
    private final Counter c;

    public SyncTest(Counter c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    static class Counter {
        int count = 0;
        // non static but synchronized for all (since they use the same `counter` object)
        synchronized void inc() {
            count++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        test();
    }

    public void test() {
            this.c.inc();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // one counter for all
        Counter counter = new Counter();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            SyncTest thread = new SyncTest(counter);
            executor.execute(thread);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (true) {
            if (executor.isTerminated()) {
                System.out.println("a " + counter.count);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you sir, since the synchronized method won't work for this case, in what circumstances does  the synchronized  method work? Could you please give an example?

Comment: @ee there are many ways to do so, I've updated the answer with two

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: Declare your lock variable on the next line after the variable(s) that you want to protect with it, and declare it with the same keywords.  E.g.,

```
public class aaa implements Runnable {
    static int count = 0;
    static Lock countLock = new ReentrantLock();
    ...
```

If you read deeply enough into any of the other answers here, then you will see why this helps.